# Inexplicable behavior when using Laravel validation on this array

Tags: php, laravel, validation, undefined-behavior

I think the best way to explain my question is by showing this *Minimal Reproducable Code Example*. I know the code is ugly, but it's about the example.

```
$data = [
        'choices' => 
        [
            [
                "id" => 56,
                "is_default" => true,
                "label" => "Choice A",
                "value" => "notAnInteger"
            ],
            [
                "is_default" => false,
                "label" => "Choice B",
                "value" => "2"
            ],
            [
                "id" => 22,
                "is_default" => false,
                "label" => "Choice C",
                "value" => "3"
            ]
        ]
    ];
    
    $loadedRules = [
        'id' => 'nullable|integer|gt:0',
        'label' => 'required|string|between:1,255',
        'is_default' => 'required|boolean',
        'value' => 'required'
    ];
    
    $rules = [];
    
    foreach($loadedRules as $key => $rulesStr) 
    {
        $rules['*.' . $key] = $rulesStr;
    }
    $rules['*.value'] = 'required|integer';

    echo '<pre>';
    
    echo "RULES:\n";
    var_dump($rules);

    echo "\n\nINPUT CHOICES:\n";
    var_dump($data['choices']);

    $validator = Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::make($data['choices'], $rules);

    echo "\n\nValue of 0'th choice:\n";
    var_dump($data['choices'][0]['value']);
    
    echo "\n\nERRORS:\n"; var_dump($validator->errors());

    if($validator->fails()) 
    {
        echo "There are errors.";
    }
    else {
        echo 'All valid';
    }
    
    echo '</pre>';
```

The problem is that Laravel generates the following validation errors:

- "The 0.id must be greater than 4."
- "The 2.id must be greater than 4."
- "The 0.value must be an integer."

I assume that the code shows what the intention is. But I can't explain the actual behavior of Laravel. I must be overlooking something, but I just don't see it, or it could be that I don't understand the usage of Laravel here correctly.

I cannot find out where the '4' comes from in the validation errors. This '4' nowhere occurs in my code at all. And among other things, therefore I don't trust the code since there could be more going wrong implicitly.

Comment: What do you get when you dump the rules? The [gt rule](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-gt) means greater than another field, not a number. You'll want [min](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-min) for that

Comment: In my code example, the rules are var_dump'ed and this is the output:
object(Illuminate\Support\MessageBag)#413 (2) {
  ["messages":protected]=>
  array(3) {
    ["0.id"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(32) "The 0.id must be greater than 4."
    }
    ["2.id"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(32) "The 2.id must be greater than 4."
    }
    ["0.value"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(31) "The 0.value must be an integer."
    }
  }
  ["format":protected]=>
  string(8) ":message"
}

Comment: This is kinda just what happens when you try to validate an Array of things: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#validating-arrays. What do you _want_ it to say? Cause you can override the Messages: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#manual-customizing-the-error-messages. (Sidenote, not sure where the `4` comes from either)

Comment: @aynber that could be the problem. Could be that I'm just using the wrong validation rule... ‍♂️

Comment: Sidenote, this works if you use `choices` and `choices.*` (and fix `gt:0` to `min:0` as aynber says): `$rules = ['choices' => 'array', 'choices.*.id' => 'nullable|integer|min:0', 'choices.*.label' => 'required|string|between:1,255', 'choices.*.is_default' => 'required|boolean', 'choices.*.value' => 'required'];`. Using that as `$rules` causes `All Valid` to be output 

Comment: Seems like gt works for integers as well, at least if you validate just one element it works

Comment: Thank you all for the help. I was indeed overlooking the fact that the `gt` rule had to be `min`. So even though it turns out the problem wasn't that complex, I'm sure I would have wasted too much time on this and had a lot more frustration.

Comment: @StewieSWS Yup, since there is no `0` in the validation fields. Since they are validating `$data['chioces']` instead of `$data`, you end up with 4 "fields": `[0 => ['id' => ..., 'is_default' => ...]` (and so on). So `gt:0` is saying "Greater than field 0", which as 4 elements, `id`, `is_default`, `label` and `value`. This _can_ work with `gt:0`, if you validate `$data`, and define your keys as `choices.*.id` (and so on). Weird bug you found here, but makes sense once you break it down.

Comment: @Tim Lewis ooh, i see! Thank you for the explanataion!